# NameNotFoundException: Name is not bound in this Context. Unable to find

Tags: java, xml, database, tomcat, datasource

I'm having a problem with the deploy of an application (war file) in tomcat.

the application has defined a reference to the JNDI datasource, in web.xml and SpringDataJPAContext.xml (application works ok on jboss). For my part, I am defining the datasource inside tomcat, in server.xml and in a file inside conf/Catalina/localhost ([name-application].xml).

Within the application I have defined...

> in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>JDBC Data Source</description>
    <res-ref-name>mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <mapped-name>java:mydb</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

> in WEB-INF/classes/SpringDataJPAContext.xml:

```
<beans: bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans: property name="jndiName" value="java:jdbc/mydb"/>
</beans:bean>
```

For my part, I'm testing on tomcat ...

> in server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    ....
    <Resource name="mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="user" password="pass" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

> in conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml:

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="mydb" global="mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

But, when I start tomcat I get an error that does not find the name of the datasource. I'm getting:

```
"javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]."
```

I have tried different configurations, but the error keeps coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes and let me know of it works:

1. Remove the `<mapped-name>java:mydb </mapped-name>`  tag from web.xml
2. Just use `<beans: property name="jndiName" value="mydb"/>` in the spring data xml
    or else put the full jndi as `value="java:comp/env/mydb"`

The exception that you have pasted looks odd to me. "[jdbc/mydb]" tomcat is searching for the tree branch jdbc and then mydb inside it which might be due to the mapped name and spring data xml "jboss" prefix.
It should ideally have searched for "mydb" directly in the jndi tree.

Please let me know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small mistake in my post. The value of the jndi is: value="java:jdbc/mydb" (I already edited it).

I made the change in SpringDataJPAContext.xml (I added "comp/env" and deleted the prefix "jdbc") ... and I no longer get the same error. Now I have another error:

```
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringDataJPAContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.isValid(I)Z
```

Answer (score 0):

SpringDataJPAContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <repositories base-package="cl.cgr.sistradoc.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/sistradocgi" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cgrPU" /> <!-- agregando configuraciones custom repository Lorenzo  -->
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="cl.cgr.sistradoc.entity" />
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the last error: it was the version of the postgresql driver.